# How to position div elements

Tags: css, html, iframe

I'm new to designing web pages. I need to create a page that will have 2 sections.

The first section will have a logo on the top left corner.  The second section will be in the middle of the page with some content generated by iframes.

I have put 2 div tags on the page: one for the image and another for content like this:

```
  <div class="logo">
      <a href="http://somelink.com/">
      <img src=someimage.png'/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <iframe src="somepage.php></iframe>
  </div>
```

How can I do it?

Than you

Answer (score 1):

#### Try something like this:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjfxq/**

Use `CSS` to position your elements. To learn more about styling, try this interactive tutorial:

- http://www.codecademy.com/courses/css-coding-with-style/0/1

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo"><a href="http://somelink.com/"><img src='http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_128.png'/></a></div>

<div id="content"><iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**There are a million other ways to do this**, but your question was basic, so my answer was basic.

Comment: Thank's for your quick response.

Comment: If it fits your style, please mark it as accepted using the green arrow next to the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.logo
{
float: left;
}
.content
{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: He currently has his `content` set as a `class`, not an `id`. You should probably reference that without providing `HTML`.

Comment: He has different classes for each <div>, so i mentioned 2 different classes. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: How should I remove borders around a logo?

Comment: Try adding the style  border: none; in the class .logo